# List of names Combobox Windows C++

Tags: c++, winforms, combobox, handle

This is my first time trying to have some sort of GUI for my code and I wanted to use Windows Forms with Visual Studio in C++.

I am trying to fill the options of a `combobox` with options that are found in an external list.
I have a function that passes a list of strings and I want to use that list as the source.
The code I tried:

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_names; i++) {
                this->cover_material->Items->Add(list_of_names[i]);
        }
```

Where `number_of_names` is a predefined int and `list_of_names` is a list of strings.

I understand that this code asks for an object type, but I can't find how to properly define that.
The following code I found online works to add items to the list:

```cpp
    this->cover_material->Items->Add("some text");
```

However, when I change it to passing a string it does not work:

```cpp
    string text = "some text";
    this->cover_material->Items->Add(text);
```

Passing a handle does work:

```cpp
    String^ text = "some text";
    this->cover_material->Items->Add(text);
```

However, I can't find how to change the string of that handle. Now I assume that changing that string is possible, but I also think this is not the correct way to add items to the `combobox`.
Can someone help me in the right direction?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you need that collection to fill a ComboBox, why don't you use an `array<System::String^>^` instead? It would also allow to set the DataSource of your ComboBox. If you cannot do that, for some reason, you can marshal each std::string to a managed String^, e.g., `cover_material->Items->Add(msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(list_of_names[i]));`